# Unable to parse JWK in Java

Tags: java, jwt, jwk, nimbus-jose-jwt

I implemented a rest authorization server that returns the public-key for a given keyId in the JWK format using the `com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.13` package. The code looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth2", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface Rest {
...
    @GetMapping("/public-key/{keyId}")
    @Operation(summary = "Return the public key corresponding to the key id")
    JWK getPublicKey(@PathVariable String keyId);
}

public class RestController implements Rest {
.....
 public JWK getPublicKey(String keyId) {
         byte[] publicKeyBytes = ....
         RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));
         JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .keyID(keyId)
                .algorithm(new Algorithm(publicKey.getAlgorithm()))
                .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
                .build();
         return jwk;
    }
}
```

This code returns a JWK key in the following format:

```
{
    "keyStore": null,
    "private": false,
    "publicExponent": {},
    "modulus": {},
    "firstPrimeFactor": null,
    "secondPrimeFactor": null,
    "firstFactorCRTExponent": null,
    "secondFactorCRTExponent": null,
    "firstCRTCoefficient": null,
    "otherPrimes": [],
    "requiredParams": {
        "e": "some-valid-exponent",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "n": "some-valid-modulus"
    },
    "privateExponent": null,
    "x509CertChain": null,
    "algorithm": {
        "name": "RSA",
        "requirement": null
    },
    "keyOperations": null,
    "keyID": "some-valid-key-id",
    "x509CertURL": null,
    "x509CertThumbprint": null,
    "x509CertSHA256Thumbprint": null,
    "parsedX509CertChain": null,
    "keyUse": {
        "value": "sig"
    },
    "keyType": {
        "value": "RSA",
        "requirement": "REQUIRED"
    }
}
```

On the client side (java), I try to parse the jwk with the following code:

```
public JWK getPublicKey(String keyId) {
 String json = restTemplate.getForObject(publicUrl + "/oauth2/public-key/" + keyId, String.class);
        try {
            return JWK.parse(json);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            log.error("Unable to parse JWK", e);
            return null;
        }
}
```

However, the client is unable to parse the key since `parse` throws an exception (`Missing parameter "kty"`). I see that `JWK.parse` requires a `kty` key in main JWT josn body, while the default serialization of `JWK` embeds the `kty` key within `requiredParams` key. When I try `jwk.toString()`, I do see the `kty` key in the main json body.

Why doesn't serialization/deserialization of the native JWK object work in a straight-forward manner? What would be the best way to fix this without implementing a custom jwt structure or a serializer/deserializer?

**Update 1**: This code will work if we change the return type from `JWK` to `Map<String, Object>` or `String` and handle deserialization on the client-side. However, it would be better if the package natively does the (de)serialization for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use  `String` for (de)serialization for those facing this problem. Why, you ask? According to the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517), JWK is a string in the JSON format. While `nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt` defines a JWK object, any APIs that return valid JWK (or `JWKSet`) can assume that it's a string.

I also raised this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issues/441/unable-to-parse-jwk-in-java) with the developers of this package, and they recommended using `String` or `Map<String, Object>` for (de)serialization.

Answer (score 0):

According to a developer of the package [here](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issues/234/how-to-handle-when-single-key-is-returned#comment-39287308), a JWK set, not individual JWK, should be exposed through the endpoint (see https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens):

> Publishing a JWK set (JSON array) of multiple keys, instead of just one key at the URL is intended to facilitate smooth key roll-over. With a single key being published switching to a new key can lead to errors on the client side.
>
> Anyway, if you want to keep the one-key-per URL, I suggest you override the existing `com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet`, or implement your own single JWK source with `com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource` (possibly copying code where needed from `RemoteJWKSet`).

---

**UPDATE**: Just found out that the same serialization issue in the question exists for `JWKSet` too